# i am trying my have my program diside which to respond with but it wont work and i dont know why lua

Tags: lua

```
print ('Hello, make a face, ')
local face = io.read()
local t = {"{:) , :), "}
if local face (t1) then print (" :0 ")
if local (t2) then print (" :) ")
```

please help me fix it and help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: It's not clear what problems you have and what you want to ask, and the code contains a lot of basic syntax errors. You may read some lua tutorials first.

Comment: You need to study logic and programming more.

Comment: I am counting 8 issues in 5 lines of code, that's a new record ^^

Answer (score 4):

Let's break down your program to help understand your assumptions and how to correct them.

```lua
print ('Hello, make a face, ')
```

This does exactly what it you think it does, it prints the string `'Hello, make a face, '` into the console on its own line. This is correct.

```lua
local face = io.read()
```

Likewise, this correctly requests a line of text from the user, and stores it in the [local](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) variable `face`

```lua
local t = {"{:) , :), "}
```

This is the first incorrect assumption. Whilst `local t =`  would correctly assign to the value t, `{"{:) , :), "}` does not do what you seem to expect. This creates a [table](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) with one value, `"{:) , :), "`. Note that the double qoutes entirely encapsulate the value, meaning it couldn't be two seperate values. What you should have in this instance is `{":)", ":)"}`, which contains two values instead.

It's worth noting even corrected this table contains the same value twice, I am not sure that this was intended, but I cannot assume the correct formatting.

```lua
if local face (t1) then print (" :0 ")
```

There are a handful of incorrect assumptions here. `local face` in this instance is incorrect, `face` was already previously assigned as a local variable. The `local` keyword should only be used when defining the variable, not referencing it. Additionally, you seem to be attempting to compare `face` to the first entry of the table via `face (t1)`, this is very wrong, and should be done via `face == t[1]`. Note that `[1]` is used to retreive the value at position `1` from the table `t`, and equality is checked with the equality operator, `==`. Finally, you have not closed your [`if then`](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html) statement. Lua, unlike other langauges, does not support single-expression statements, and **must** be closed with an `end`.

```lua
if local (t2) then print (" :) ")
```

This contains many of the same assumptions as the previous line, though for reasons I cannot assume, you have neglected to include `face`. Additionally, this *should* probably be an `elseif` statement, rather than just another `if` statement, if the behaviour is intended to be exclusive.

All together, and with additional formatting, your code should now read

```lua
print ('Hello, make a face, ')
local face = io.read()
local t = {":)", ":)"}
if face == t[1] then 
    print (" :0 ")
elseif face == t[2] then
    print (" :) ")
end
```

I strongly suggest reading up on the [Basics of Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html), or even some tutorials, as you seem to be just guessing about the syntax. Lua is a very well documented langauge with plenty of tutorials, including a [Codecadamy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-lua) course.

Comment: bro thank you i read the basics and i thought i did the if and local stamens correct but not thaks